# Firestore list only shows updated item (Angular + Ionic)

Tags: angular, list, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with angular+ionic+firestore. See below my codes. I do initialiseItems() within filteredMarkers(). However whenever I update an item in the list and go back to check the list, only the updated item is shown. What problems am I looking at here? Thanks a looot for your help❤️

[ionic html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXwhm.png)
[angular code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TurVQ.png)

Comment: You can use code snippets for paste code in question. It will help other people better read and search for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you use `Promise` instead `Observable`. When you created the component, `Promise` resolved once, and when you updated your collection you didn't see any changes. If you will use `Observable` all will be ok.